# rotate hex image in report builder

Tags: xml, reporting-services, reportbuilder, rdl

I want to rotate the image I converted from hex image to png in a picturebox in Report Builder by 90 degrees. I couldn't find any way through my research. Can you help me?

Here s my picturebox properties;

Picture box fx

[image: 1]

And if i can, i can change xml code in behind, if u tell me how can give rotate angle to my image tag. Like this;

Image xml codes

[image: 2]

How will i give 90 degree rotate to picturebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a function to rotate the image and call the function from your
image value

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rotatefliptype?view=netframework-4.8

```
Public Function EditImage(ByVal picbytes as Byte()) as Byte()

    Dim ms as System.IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
    Dim rms as System.IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
    Dim bm as System.Drawing.Bitmap

    ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(picbytes, 0, picbytes.Length)
    bm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(ms)

        ' Image manipulation code will go here
    bm.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone)

    rms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()
    bm.Save(rms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Return rms.ToArray()
End Function
```

[image]